# How to extract audio files from Diablo 3 installation?

Tags: diablo-iii

I love Diablo 3 music (who doesn't) and I would like to extract the audio tracks from my installed files and listening to with an external music player, for my pleasure. Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MPQ Explorer](http://www.zezula.net/en/mpq/download.html).

This lets you open Blizzard's MPQ file format, which is where they store all their game assets including music.  The application has the ability to extract sound files from the MPQ files.

http://www.ehow.com/how_4705307_extract-music-world-warcraft.html provides an example on how to do it on World of Warcraft.  The only issue is that I don't think anyone has bothered finding which MPQ contains Diablo III's music yet, but there is only a limited number of options.

Comment: Thank you I found them. They are located in file Sound.mpq inside some subfolders name with pattern Music_<Act>_<Zone> in SounbBank folder.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, most files are in some unknown format, so you won't be able to read them. A few are in vorbis, format, including the musics.